# BBC presenter: "Some interesting thoughts there." --- What is the function of "THERE" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, syntax

This is from BBC, where people are talking about weight loss, and an expert's opinions are also broadcast. They listen to her, and after the expert finishes, the presenter says:

**"Some interesting thoughts there."** [BBC-learning-6 Minute English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eE7yFxKkyM) (see: 27:33-27:38)

I wonder what is the function of **"there"** in that sentence? Why didn't he simply say **"Some interesting thoughts."**, and he further felt the need to add a **"there"**?

Comment: "Some interesting thoughts" might invite replies, but the show is over, and 'there' refers to "in the studio" or "in that broadcast".

Comment: This is a completely valid question. One of the things learners often don't know is this type of spoken discourse marker. here and there are often used like that.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Or "in what the last speaker said".

Comment: there functions in several ways here. [haha]

Comment: @WeatherVane - knowing the BBC, and British understatement, 'some interesting thoughts there' could mean 'they're all bat shit crazy'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey don't get me started on their trailers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"there" in that video comes at the end of comments by the presenter about what a doctor has just said.

It functions as a **discourse marker** and serves to connect his thoughts (Some interesting thoughts there) to what has been said. It is also **deictic**: *it points* to the previous comments, as if to say: those comments are interesting.

> Discourse markers that organise what we say.    Some discourse markers are
> used **to start and to end conversations**. Some are used to start new
> topics or to change topics.

[discourse markers_same across all varieties of English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/discourse-markers-so-right-okay)

Also, "there" also means "her comments".

Comment: +1, agree, but why not here? What would be the difference? Semantically, I think, none.

Comment: @LucianSava in Portuguese, lá e aqui. In Spanish, alla y aqui.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't the smallest idea of Spanish, or Portuguese. I'm a native from Romania.

Comment: @LucianSava **Sorry**: I'm pretty sure the idea is the same in Roumaian. If the presenter were to continue his interview, he could say here, also. meaning: in this conversation. It is still deictic and a discourse marker. He uses there because he is no longer talking to the woman.

Comment: Oh, I see it, indeed :).

Answer (score 2):

“There” in this context indicates that the speaker is talking about opinions they just heard. You can think of the following as an equivalent thought:

> ‘There were some interesting thoughts shared in that conversation [we just heard].’

The same thought could be expressed without the word ‘there’, as within the context the subject could be assumed:

> ‘Some interesting thoughts…’

See
[Use of ‘There’ in English](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/465/there)

Comment: This answer citing that page does really answer the question. There was is not the same thing exactly as putting there at the end of sentences.